# How to import Tailwind configuration values from Qwik components?

Tags: tailwind-css, vite, qwik

I'm trying to import some configurations from Tailwin in Qwik component.

Inside `tailwind.config.js` I have this code:

```
// tailwind.config.js file

const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')
// custom configuration

const { sm, md, lg, xl } = defaultTheme.screens

module.exports.sm = sm.replace('px', '') * 1;
module.exports.md = md.replace('px', '') * 1;
module.exports.lg = lg.replace('px', '') * 1;
module.exports.xl = xl.replace('px', '') * 1;
```

And inside my Qwik component:

```
import { sm, md, lg, xl } from '../../tailwind.config.js'
```

However, I get this error:

> [vite] Internal server error: require is not defined

How can I export config from Tailwind and import it in my Qwik components?